# Does Crypto class support SHA384?

Tags: apex, crypto, algorithm

We are calling a service from salesforce. This service is expecting a specific hash in the httpHeaders collection of the HTTP Request.

The service is written in .NET and the hash is computed using SHA384 in C#.
Here is the sample C# code.

```
SHA384 shaM = new SHA384Managed();
    byte[] bye = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("IAMSTUMPED");
    byte[] buffer = shaM.ComputeHash(bye);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; buffer != null && i < buffer.Length; i++) 
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", buffer[i]);
    }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output of this is:

> **199978467e452a6a937f90936e058dd9556412c0479fc3471d27f29135ecbcec534f8b29cd8ef6a38de9250237f603e8**

How can I get Apex to produce the same output as the .NET code? I don't want to hard-code the hash since the key in the example can be changed multiple times.

I am going through the documentation on [Crypto](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) class and the method that looks most promising is generateDigest. This does not seem to support SHA384.

Here is my apex code.

```
Blob urlBlob = Blob.valueOf('IAMSTUMPED');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', urlBlob);
string token = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
System.Debug(token);
//Outputs: CKl2baWkEngT4+gXasfpeA==
encryptedData = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', urlBlob);
token = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
System.Debug(token);
//Outputs: Ak/2rdtJWyVe2/lXgoBnojmSGqM=
encryptedData = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', urlBlob);
token = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
System.Debug(token);
//Outputs: 4Oq4exMWa9kNcNVj3Gu4Ce3+9/rUVE5yrqRpc7NZCdw=
encryptedData = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-512', urlBlob);
token = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
System.Debug(token);
//Ouputs: 290Z3HYWsWtEqqtIgMvr2UxilQmJVnwAQKbeOxAZ6ousKC9ZbvoTbzOXfzA71SRYTNLQXos9xJT2ZnSst7i3hw==
```

I have tried using every single algorithm that is listed in the documentation. How can I generate the same hash that the C# code is generating?

Comment: Did you try `SHA-384` itself? Just because it is not documented does not mean it's not worth testing.

Comment: In addition to the above - Your blob in the C# is `IAMNOWSTUMPED` yet in the apex code you are using a different value `IAMSTUMPED`.

Comment: is changing the C# code to use one of the algorithms that Salesforce is documented to support not an option?

Comment: @Eric Yes. I realized that later, but the problem still exists. I am using the same values now.

Comment: @DerekF That is not an option as there are other clients that are using the service currently.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Interesting, SHA-384 does work, but it is creating a different token string. Perhaps I need to look into the EncodingUtil class instead.
```GZl4Rn5FKmqTf5CTbgWN2VVkEsBHn8NHHSfykTXsvOxTT4spzY72o43pJQI39gPo```

Comment: Your C# output is hex, but your Apex output is base64 encoded. Convert one to the other, and it should match.

Comment: @DerekF I was answering the same time, you were posting the comment. Thank You All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Adrian pointed me in the right direction here. **The SHA-384, although not documented is supported by the Crypto class**. So I had to make a slight change to my code. Here is my code that creates the same output as the C# code. I have tested this with a couple of keys other than "IAMSTUMPED" and they produce the same output.

```
Blob urlBlob = Blob.valueOf('IAMSTUMPED');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-384', urlBlob);
string token = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(encryptedData);
System.Debug(token);
```

Comment: Given that SHA-384 is not documented and that the underlying implementation may be [provider based](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) and Salesforce might choose to change providers there is a (small?) chance that SHA-384 support might be removed as a side effect in the future. I would create a case to check if this is a supported platform feature i.e. a documentation miss rather than an accidental feature not checked by tests.

Comment: Good point. I will get on it rightaway. Also I have requested the service providers to switch to SHA-512 which is documented in Apex. However that may not happen or take a very long time.

Comment: Yep - smart to see where you can get to taking both approaches.